# How to compare values and group using mongo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to check if two dates are equal and then group another result based on the Date.

```js
{"creationDate": "2021/3/19",
 "_id": "60549366ab4eb00aa1ed2fd9",
 "avgPower": 8241,
 "WaterConsumption": 22},

{"creationDate": "2021/3/19",
 "_id": "605493f4ab4eb00aa1ed2fda",
 "avgPower": 8241,
 "WaterConsumption": 22},

{"creationDate": "2021/2/17",
 "_id": "60549433ab4eb00aa1ed2fdb",
 "avgPower": 4300,
 "WaterConsumption": 32,}
```

I was able to aggregate using a string like the following example. This was the farthest I could go aggregating.

```js
let dateTwo = await Measure.aggregate([
  {$match: {creationDate: "2021/3/19"}}, <=======
  {$group: {_id: "$user", total: {$sum: "$WaterConsumption"}}}
]);
```

### What the code should do:

```
let dateTwo = await Measure.aggregate([
  {$match: {creationDate: ==>Check if the dates are equal<==}},
  {$group: {_id: "$user", total: {$sum: "$WaterConsumption"}}}
]);
```

### Expected Result

```js
{"creationDate": "2020/3/19", "_id": "someID", "WaterConsumption": 44}
```

How can I declare an expression to check if creationDates are equal? I'm really struggling on this. I was able to do this using JavaScript but I can't figure out how can I do this using mongo.

Comment: I cant understand how the code you provided does not satisfy your need. You wante to get total `WaterConsumption` for a specific date.

Comment: Exactly! It's grouping, but instead of passing the string "2021/3/19" I want to check the dates automatically. In other words I only want to aggregate if the dates are equals otherwise not.

Comment: Do you want to get total per date?

Comment: The total part is working. I want to check if there are equal dates. Then I want to sum WaterConsumption. The problem is that there is nothing checking if the dates are equals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using the following line:

```
    let dateTwo = await Measure.aggregate([
        {$group: {_id: {creationDate: "$creationDate"}, 
        total: {$sum: "$WaterConsumption"}}}
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this is what you are trying to figure out. If not please try to rephrase your question.

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wknlEIl5MvM)

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $match: {
    creationDate: "2021/3/19"
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$creationDate",
    ids: {
      $push: "$_id"
    },
    total: {
      $sum: "$WaterConsumption"
    }
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    "creationDate": "$_id",
    "_id": "$ids",
    "WaterConsumption": "$total"
  }
})
```

Comment: I want the $match part to check if there are equal dates in my collection, if yes I want to group like: creationDate : {function that checks if there are equal creationDates} if creationDate: true, then group: WaterConsumption. I tried to use some logic to express this better. I edited the code.